# Do you extend Java, to make games, or can you just use JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe

I'm starting to create my own side scroller, in Java. I think I've read that, when you create a game in Java, there is something you can extend your class with, like `GamePanel`.

Is this true, or can you just use JFrame for your Java games?

Comment: Can we have more information about the game? For example, if you are using JOGL or Java3D for rendering, then those would have specific requirements for what you can draw to. If you're doing a 2D game and not using any libraries (i.e. overriding paintComponent()), then I guess pretty much any Swing component would work and a bunch of event listeners, but I wouldn't think that would be the most performant piece of code.

Comment: Alright! At the moment i am not using any libraries for my game.. But if i should which library is good you think?

Comment: If you're going without libraries (which IMHO isn't neccessarily a bad thing) take a look at BufferStrategy: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Java game that uses no libraries, I would suggest you extend the [Canvas](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) class and override the [paint(Graphics)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method. It is the most basic component you can use without a lot of overhead.

However, I strongly suggest you look into [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) or [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/). They both use [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/); the former is for 2D while the latter is for 2D and 3D.

To kill two birds with one stone, I would also suggest you look into [Artemis](http://www.gamadu.com/artemis/), which is an awesome Entity System that works on top of Slick. The site contains some example games to help you get started.

Comment: Note that the Slick2D forums are EXTREMELY active and helpful